# Equivalence testing with multiple means in R

Tags: r, equivalence

I have a question regarding equivalence testing with multiple means in R. 
Let's say I create a sample dataset, in which I perform a test on 4 different timepoints:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)

# Set seed
set.seed(123)

# Create dataset
timepoint <- rep(c(1,2,4,8), each=25)
test <- rep(1, 10)
value <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 50, sd = 10)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(timepoint,test,value))

df <- df %>% group_by(timepoint) %>% 
             summarize(mean=mean(value)) %>% 
             full_join(df, .)
```

**Plot**

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=as.factor(timepoint))) + 
  geom_quasirandom(aes(y = value)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(x = "Timepoint", y = "Value") +
  geom_point(aes(y = mean ), col = "Red" , shape = "-", size = 10)
```

[image]

I would like to test for equivalence; however, I do not only want to compare two groups (as with two one-sided tests, as in the [TOSTER](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TOSTER/TOSTER.pdf) package by Lakens). I would like to perform equivalence testing for multiple groups. How do you apply such a method on an experiment with more than two means?

**Question**

What is the appropriate method to do equivalence testing on an experiment with multiple dependent groups?

**Note**: The question is about the statistical methods to perform equivalence testing. The `R` code is just to illustrate the experimental setup and data structure.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If your question is about R code, then it is off topic here. But if it is about what statistics you can run to test multiple means, then it is on topic. If it is the latter, please clarify and the question can be reopened.

Comment: I thought it was fairly clear that the question was primarily about stats as is. I had planned on giving an answer when I had a chance. The point about the r package just seems to be am example; the question seems to asking for general ideas.

Comment: @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica The question is intended to learn about the statistical method to test equivalence when dealing with multiple dependent means. The R code is merely an illustrative example to clarify the question and my dataset/structure. I have tried to clarify that in the question.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use a one-way ANOVA?

Comment: @Igor F. Maybe my statistical knowledge isn't developed enough to fully understand the ins and outs of an ANOVA, however, I was not aware that it could be useful for equivalence testing?

Comment: @ Igor F. How do you determine the equivalence margin for three or more groups of ANOVA?

Comment: This is very interesting topic. Should we call it a "related 4-groups equivalence test"?
For the classical significance-test for the four independent groups, that is an elementary problem, all you have to do is  Anova. However, that is an equivalence test and related group. I cannot imagine.

Comment: One way to define equivalence for oneway anova is in terms of effect size. This version is referenced as Wellek Anova. (Aside: I'm currently implementing it for statsmodels in Python.)

Comment: Wellek, Stefan (2010). Testing statistical hypotheses of equivalence and noninferiority